# Expand table rows - toggle

Tags: jquery

I have a table that is using expand rows feature. I am trying to add an Expand All to expand all, using 'toggleClass'.

The issue I am finding is if a row is already expanded, and I click on expand all, that open row then closes because I am asking it to toggle from open to close. Makes perfect sense.

Is it possible to make all rows open even if a few are already open? Or conversely, close all even if a few are open and closed? Without having to use two buttons - one for open all and one to close all (which is a simple changeClass)

```
$('table').on('click', 'tr.parent ', function () {
$(this).closest('tbody').toggleClass('open');
});
$(".expandall").click(function () {
$("tbody").toggleClass('open');
});
```

Any help appreciated. https://codepen.io/jjspelman/pen/GwRyNE

Comment: Are you opposed to having two buttons even if one is only visible at a time? E.g. `Expand All` is displayed by default at page load; clicking it (1) expands all rows then (2) hides itself & displays a `Collapse All` in its place. Said `Collapse All` would then perform the opposite. The issue with only having a single button is you otherwise need a way to track the "state" of whether or not you want your single button to expand all or collapse all; the simplest way to do that is to have state-specific buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my comment, this is easily solved by just having two different buttons but with only one displayed at a time. This way, rather than trying to track the state of whether you want your single button to act as an `Expand All` or a `Collapse All` is inherent in which button is displayed. To the user, it just looks like the text label of the "one" button is changing.

HTML changes:

```
<thead>
<tr class="tableheader">
    <th class="expandall"><i style="color: #fff;" class="far fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></th>
    <th class="expandall" style="text-align: left;">Expand All</th>
    <th class="collapseall" style="text-align: left;">Collapse All</th> <!-- New cell/button here -->
    <th>Column<br />One</th>
    <th>Column<br />Two</th>
    <th>Column<br />Three</th>
    <th>Column<br />Four</th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

(You can apply inline styles or use an existing CSS rule, as I did, to hide the `Collapse All` button on initial page load)

JS changes:

```
$(".expandall").click(function () {
  $(this).hide();
  $(".collapseall").show();
  $("tbody").addClass('open');
});
$(".collapseall").click(function () {
  $(this).hide();
  $(".expandall").show();
  $("tbody").removeClass('open');
});
```

Forked CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LXYeQR

Comment: I was initially thinking about changing the text of the "Expand All" but the idea of hiding a button seems more practical. As you mentioned having to track the state may not be the best idea. Great solution.